# Data of left turn signal

Tags: intersection, road

I wonder if there is any publically available dataset that has left turn signal information (say, in the U.S.)? For example, in right-hand traffic countries, major intersections may have a left-oriented arrow to protect left-turning cars.

I've looked into the [traffic_light](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway=traffic%20signals?uselang=en-US) tag in OSM, but seems there is no left-turn protection information.

Comment: If it is open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: They did ask on Open Data. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/protected-left-turn-traffic-signal-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that this data exists for all of the US, but certain cities or states may provide it.

Searching for "[road intersections](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=road%20intersection&start=1&num=20&focus=layers-weblayers-features)" on ArcGIS.com, I found that some state DOT's (Departments of Transportation) provide point data for intersections. Eg, Florida DOT provides a layer with very minimal attributes, and nothing about left turn signals.

West Virginia DOT provides a [feature layer](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ffb12619e413401cbbb9827f942ccd06) with "Large Arrows Two Directions, Turn Lane Signs, Advance Arrows," at least according to the layer description. The actual feature data looks like this:

[image] [image] [image]

So...maybe the left turn arrow information is in "MUDCDCODE" or "SIGN_SYS"...your guess is as good as mine. There's probably an explanation *somewhere* on the [WVDOT website](http://transportation.wv.gov/highways/programplanning/gti/GIS/Pages/DataCatalog.aspx).

Once you've looked at all 50 states, you might want to try looking for data from the [larger cities in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population). Don't bother with small towns, frankly they're doing well if they even have a website.

Some of the more affluent/densely populated counties also provide some geospatial data, although you'll probably catch this when you search city-level.